# How to calculate AVG of multiple fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how can I calculate avg of multiple fields? I would like to calculate AVG of field1 and field2 (one value for this two fields) group by NAME

...
`    {

name: "Tom",

id:"123",

additional_info:

[ {diff: "X", params: [{field1: 5, field2: 4}]},

{diff: "Y", params: [{filed1: 3, field2: 4}]},

{diff: "Z", params: [{field1: 2, field2: 5}]},

]
}`

Comment: Please try to add what you have tried , and where you are struck or facing issue , as Stackoverflow is a community to help users solve problem by themselfs rather than get ready made solutions

Answer (score 0):

Try this and let me know if this works please provide sample data so other can test and get an idea of Schema.

```
   db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     {
       $group:
         {
           _id: "id",
           {additional_info: $in[{params: $in[{avg: "$field"}]}]}
           avgQuantity: { $avg: "$quantity" }
         }
     }
   ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

https://mongoplayground.net/

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "avgCompTime": {
        "$avg": {
          "$divide": [
            {
              "$add": [
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$minCompTime",
                    "$maxCompTime"
                  ],
                  
                },
                {
                  "$ifNull": [
                    "$maxCompTime",
                    "$minCompTime"
                  ],
                  
                },
                
              ]
            },
            2
          ]
        }
      },
  
    }
  }
])
```